# Django DB query becomes 'None' as seen with DEBUG=True inside a long-running management command

Tags: python, django, database, django-database

I am using Django 2.2 in several modes, one of which is a long-running management command which runs under Supervisord to process inbound Slack messages.  This has worked fine with several weeks of testing.  However, today I witnessed something disturbing which I can't explain.

I am running all this in a TEST environment, so I have DEBUG set to True as well as my logger debug levels turned up.  Because of this, I can see every DB query and have a good idea of where the problem occurred.

The task had been running fine for about 17 hours, which is nothing compared to how long it has run successfully in the past (many days).  What happened was, the actual query that was supposed to go out to the DB started being blank or empty.  It showed as 'None' in the DB log.  The query is a simple object filter:

```
if not bool(SlackChannel.objects.filter(id=event['channel'])):
    return
```

This is what it began to show like:

```
2020-05-29 10:58:36,001 DEBUG utils (0.000) None; args=('SKFHJ7H5S6',)
```

which, when all is well, should be something like:

```
2020-05-29 10:58:36,001 DEBUG utils (0.000) SELECT `item`.`id`, `item`.`name`, `item`.`info` FROM `item` WHERE `item`.`id` = 'SKFHJ7H5S6'; args=('SKFHJ7H5S6',)
```

Once it got in this mode, it was perfectly reproducible. Then when I later restarted the process, the problem went away for a while, but eventually returned.  Since then I have noticed the same pattern over and over.

Also of note.. I have 2 threads in this task.  Queries continued to work fine in the other thread (although, these queries are for entirely different objects), even after the thread with this problem began to manifest.  Additionally, the other Django tasks I have + the web server all continued to work normally.

What might cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [some back and forth](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/issues/721) with the Slack Client API developer, and some additional testing, I have reached the conclusion that there is a very high probability that this is caused by poor interaction between the Slack Client and Django.  This is possibly due to async, as Django 2.2 does not support async, even though I am running the Slack Client in "sync mode".

The Slack Client developer advised a solution might be to decouple Django's handling of messages from the reception of the messages using a Q, which I concur with.  However, having a different approach already implemented, a faster solution which seems to work > 99% of the time has been to just have Supervisord auto-restart the process on an hourly basis.  If you are going to be building a solution with these 2 modules from the ground up, you should consider the Q approach.